# Finding a square root in a cyclotomic field

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Let $x\in\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p}]$. Suppose that
$$x=a_0+a_1\zeta_p+...+a_{p-2}\zeta_p^{p-2},\quad a_i\in\mathbb{Q}$$
and that $x$ has a square root in $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p}]$, i.e. there exists an element $$\sqrt{x}=b_0+b_1\zeta_p+...+b_{p-2}\zeta_p^{p-2}\in\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p}],\quad b_i\in\mathbb{Q}$$
such that $(\sqrt{x})^2=x$. The question is, given the existence of the square root, do we have any concrete and efficient algorithm (preferably in a practical sense) to find $b_i$ apart from brute-force solving equations? Any related result or comment is welcome.

Comment: Do you know  such an efficient algorithm for rational numbers ?

Comment: @GreginGre , I believe if a/b is a square, one can take the square roots of a and b separately and solve the root of a/b, and I would consider taking square roots of integers efficient.

Answer (score 0):

First you can catch all your $\sqrt x$ just with Galois theory. You are surely aware of this, but I recall the details that we need. For simplicity, given an odd prime $p$, let $K=\mathbb Q (\zeta)$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive $p$-th root of $1$. It is well known that the extension $K/\mathbb Q$ is normal, with cyclic Galois group $G$ of order $p-1$. This cyclic $G$ contains a unique automorphism of order $2$, the so called "complex conjugation" sending $\zeta$ to its inverse. Noting $K^+$ its fixed field, the extension $K/K^+$  is quadratic, $K=K^+(\sqrt x)$, with $x$ in $K^+$, and this quadratic extension is uniquely determined by the class of $x$ modulo the squares of $K^+$. One canonical $x$ is $\delta=\zeta+ \zeta^{-1}$ and all the $x$ 's we want will have the form $x= \delta. y^2$, with a non zero $y \in K^+$. But $K^+=\mathbb Q (\delta)$ is explicitly known, and this explicit knowledge is as effective as any algorithm, I think.

Comment: I am sorry I did not quite follow. Would you be so kind to explain why x is in $K^+$, and why $\sqrt{x}$ is not in $K^+$, as I personally think they are neither necessarily true?

Comment: Given a quadratic extension $M/L$ of characteristic $\neq 2$, the usual theory (algorithm) for solving an equation of degree 2 gives $M=L(\sqrt D)$, where the discriminant $D \in L^*, \notin {L^*}^{2}$ . Did I skip something ?

Comment: Perhaps I did not quite understand the argument, but say $p=5, \sqrt{x}=1+\zeta_5^2+\zeta_5^3$, with $x=2+\zeta^2+\zeta^3$. Then both $\sqrt{x}$ and $x$ are fixed under the conjugation, right?

Comment: It's my turn not to understand. Given a 2-nd degree polynomial $X^2 +bx+c$, with $b,c$ in the base field, its discriminant is $D=b^2 - 4c$, and its roots are $-b \pm \sqrt D$, so the quadratic field obtained by adding the roots is $M=L(\sqrt D)$, isn't it ?

Comment: But I never assumed $D$ is not a square in the base field. So I guess the extension you mentioned can be trivial?

Comment: Sorry for the confuse explanation. In cold blood, let us look again at your question, which is the characterization of non null square elements $x \in K=\mathbf Q(\zeta_p)$, more precisely $x=y^2, y\in K^*$. For this, I suggested to introduce the subfield $K^+$ fixed by complex conjugation, which is explicitly known, more precisely $ K^+=\mathbf Q(\zeta_p + {\zeta_p}^{-1})=\mathbf Q$(cos$(2\pi/p))$.

Comment: If $y\in K^+$, there is no problem in writing down $y$. If not, $K$ is obtained from $K^+$, first by adding $y=\sqrt x$; second by adding $i$ sin$(2\pi/p)= \sqrt \delta$,  with $\delta$ = (cos$^{2}(2\pi/p)-1)$. By Kummer's theory (or by direct calculations on trinomials of 2nd degree), this means that $x=\delta z^2$, with $z\in {K^+}^*$.

Comment: “If $y\in K^+$, there is no problem in writing down $y$”, which is exactly what I was wondering. Let’s just suppose we use the previous example. The question is when one is given $x=2+\zeta_5^2+\zeta_5^3$, how should he compute out its square root efficiently using a systematic algorithm. There is no better way than solving a bunch of coefficient equations as far as I know, which is extremely inefficient in practice.